# How to capture HTTP response with C#?

Tags: c#, httpresponse, packet-capture

How do I capture HTTP response when the request is made by web browser?

Webpage retrieves data (with post) from a service.
Service returns a json object. What I want is to capture that json and parse it in realtime.

What would be the simplest way to do it?

Comment: Do you need to do this server-side or client-side?

Comment: Client-side. Web browser displays data (ajax/json) and I need to capture that data on the fly and bind to gridview for modifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/), perhaps with the [JSON viewer](http://www.codeplex.com/JsonViewer) add-on.

From the homepage:

> Fiddler is a Web Debugging Proxy which
>   logs all HTTP(S) traffic between your
>   computer and the Internet. Fiddler
>   allows you to inspect all HTTP(S)
>   traffic, set breakpoints, and "fiddle"
>   with incoming or outgoing data.
>   Fiddler includes a powerful
>   event-based scripting subsystem, and
>   can be extended using any .NET
>   language.

Comment: "capture that json and parse it in realtime" - s/he needs a programmatic solution, not a one-shot data

Comment: But, as the description says, Fiddler can be extended using any .NET language. You could, for example, develop a plugin that does what you need, without having to write your own HTTP proxy (or packet capture tool).

Answer (score 0):

Try googling for `HttpModule` in .Net. They are some sort of filters. HTTP requests and responses flow through them and can manipulate the content.

Comment: He/she needs a client-side solution.